There is an issue with Bangla character counting on every website
Recently I've noticed a bizarre problem. I have a script that counts the number of SMS and characters typen for both Bangla and English characters. I wrote the script over 2 years ago with the help of the community and have been using this since then without any issues. Last few months all SMS was sent in English. Today when I was typing the message I noticed that the very first character I type is being counted as 91 characters which wasn't correct. for the next few (the rest of the characters) characters it counts as usual. Below I'm sharing the script -
(function ($) {
    $.fn.smsArea = function (options) {
        var e = this,
            cutStrLength = 0,

            s = $.extend({
                cut: true,
                maxSmsNum: 5,
                interval: 400,

                counters: {
                    message: $('#smsCount'),
                    character: $('#smsLength')
                },

                calculateSmsMaxLength: function (isUnicode, writtenSmsNb) {
                    if (isUnicode) {
                        if (writtenSmsNb == 0) {
                            return 70;
                        } else {
                            return (70 * (writtenSmsNb + 1)) - ((writtenSmsNb + 1) * 3);
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (writtenSmsNb == 0) {
                            return 160;
                        } else {
                            return (160 * (writtenSmsNb + 1)) - ((writtenSmsNb + 1) * 7);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, options);

        e.keyup(function () {
            clearTimeout(this.timeout);
            this.timeout = setTimeout(function () {
                var smsType,
                    smsLength = 0,
                    smsCount = -1,
                    charsLeft = 0,
                    text = e.val(),
                    isUnicode = false;

                for (var charPos = 0; charPos < text.length; charPos++) {
                    switch (text[charPos]) {
                        case "\n": case "[": case "]": case "\\": case "^": case "{": case "}": case "|": case "€":
                            smsLength += 2;
                            break;

                        default:
                            smsLength += 1;
                    }

                    if (text.charCodeAt(charPos) > 127 && text[charPos] != "€")
                        isUnicode = true;
                }

                for (var sCount = 0; sCount < s.maxSmsNum; sCount++) {
                    smsType = s.calculateSmsMaxLength(isUnicode, sCount);
                    cutStrLength = smsType;
                    if (smsLength <= smsType) {
                        smsCount = sCount + 1;
                        charsLeft = smsType - smsLength;
                        break
                    }
                }

                if (s.cut) e.val(text.substring(0, cutStrLength));
                smsCount == -1 && (smsCount = s.maxSmsNum, charsLeft = 0);

                s.counters.message.html(smsCount);
                s.counters.character.html(charsLeft);
            }, s.interval)
        }).keyup();
    }
}(jQuery));

I've trie­d to debug the problem, but with my curre­nt knowledge, I couldn't identify the­ issue. What's even more­ perplexing is that the same­ problem persists in some online­ tools. Please re­fer to the attached scre­enshot for clarification.

I am reaching out to seek your assistance in resolving this issue. I may be overlooking something, so any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you so much for your attention and participation.

Sounds like this answer could be useful?

@DouwedeHaan Thank you for your response, but this wouldn't work in these cases.

@NazmulHossain ... check the accepted answer at the link reference, not where the link lands, to see if the accepted one is more helpful?
